# Is it possible to route exception in Spring Cloud?

Tags: spring, exception, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to handle all exceptions that had been thrown by the bunch of microservices in certain one.

For example, i have microservice called **ui**. It handles all ui related stuff and serves as a Zuul gateway. It contains custom error page. Also i have microservice called **foo**. When **foo** throws exception i want **ui** to handle it i.e show **ui**'s custom error page. I dont want **foo** or any other service to contain any error pages.

Is there a way to achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an error controller and then having all your micro services redirect to that uri when experiencing an error.

Check out this tutorial he explains setting up a custom error page pretty well.

http://www.baeldung.com/custom-error-page-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks for your help